# Export SQL Database from GCP in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to export the database from my GCP to my local drive but I don't know how to achieve this. I am using Java Spring Boot for my backend. So, what would happen is that the user will be using Angular frontend and will send the request to backend to download the sql file. Then the Spring boot will communicate with GCP to export the sql file and then send to the frontend. Is there any api endpoint or library that can help me in doing this?

Comment: Do you use Cloud SQL? Do you want to export a table or the whole database?

Comment: I am using GCP Spring Boot library and I want to export the whole database